# Is there a way to expand a Vim fold automatically when your put your cursor on it?

Tags: vim

Can you have Vim expand a fold automatically when the cursor touches it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the `foldopen` option.  It controls which groups of commands will lead to
opening a fold if the cursor is moved into a closed fold.

Note that vertical movements do not open a closed fold, though.  Moreover,
there is no setting in `foldopen` to enable this behavior.  When `hor` item is
set in `foldopen` option, to open a fold one can use `h`, `l` or other
horizontal movement commands.  In case if it is crucial to automatically open
a fold on any cursor movement that touches it, one can approach this problem
by remapping some subset of vertical movement commands like it is shown below.

```
nnoremap <silent> j :<c-u>call MoveUpDown('j', +1, 1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> k :<c-u>call MoveUpDown('k', -1, 1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> gj :<c-u>call MoveUpDown('gj', +1, 1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> gk :<c-u>call MoveUpDown('gk', -1, 1)<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-d> :<c-u>call MoveUpDown("\<lt>c-d>", +1, '&l:scroll')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-u> :<c-u>call MoveUpDown("\<lt>c-u>", -1, '&l:scroll')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-f> :<c-u>call MoveUpDown("\<lt>c-f>", +1, 'winheight("%")')<cr>
nnoremap <silent> <c-b> :<c-u>call MoveUpDown("\<lt>c-b>", -1, 'winheight("%")')<cr>
function! MoveUpDown(cmd, dir, ndef)
    let n = v:count == 0 ? eval(a:ndef) : v:count
    let l = line('.') + a:dir * n
    silent! execute l . 'foldopen!'
    execute 'norm! ' . n . a:cmd
endfunction
```

An inferior, but a bit thriftier solution would be to open a fold on every
cursor movement.

```
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * silent! foldopen
```

Unfortunately, this solution is not general one.  After the fold under the
cursor is opened, the cursor is positioned on the first line of that fold.  If
this behavior is undesirable, one can follow the vertical direction of
a movement, and place the cursor on the last line of the fold when the cursor
is moving bottom-up.

```
autocmd CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * call OnCursorMove()
function! OnCursorMove()
    let l = line('.')
    silent! foldopen
    if exists('b:last_line') && l < b:last_line
        norm! ]z
    endif
    let b:last_line = l
endfunction
```

However, a fold will not be opened if the movement jumps over the fold.  For
example, `2j` on the line just above a fold will put the cursor on the line
just after that fold, not the second line in it.

Comment: Put back the `CursorMoved` solution from previous revisions.

Answer (score 3):

```
set foldopen=all
```

seems to do what you want. You may also make an autocommand for cursor movement:

```
au CursorMoved * call AutoOpen()
```

calling a function like:

```
function! AutoOpen()
  if foldclosed(".") == line(".")
    call feedkeys("zo")
  endif
endfunction
```

If you want this to also work in insert mode, use:

```
au CursorMoved,CursorMovedI * call AutoOpen()
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach has drawbacks (see my answer).

Comment: @ib: I know it's not perfect but I don't understand the drawbacks. Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: It's obvious (and already described in my answer, by the way).  Move the cursor the line next to a closed fold and move one line up (with `k`, for example).  The fold will be opened and the cursor will happen to be on the first line of that fold, not on the last one as it should be logically (meaning the semantics of line by line vertical movement).  To see another drawback put the cursor on the line just above a closed fold and type `2j`.  The cursor will jump over the whole fold, it will be moved not two lines down, but as many lines as the fold has.

Comment: These drawbacks in logical consistency regards to almost all vertical movement commands: `j`, `k`, `gj`, `gk`, `-`, `+`, `Ctrl`-`D`, `Ctrl`-`U`, `Ctrl`-`F`, `Ctrl`-`B`, etc.

Comment: @ib: Thanks for explaining; the drawbacks that you describe is what I though was normal behaviour. Also, obviously, OP didn't notice your autocommand updates.

Answer (score 1):

`:help fdo` and possibly `:help fcl` may help you. I have this line in my .vimrc:

```
set foldopen=block,hor,insert,jump,mark,percent,quickfix,search,tag,undo
```